# redirecting all traffic to my home page using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Can someone help me on how to configure my .htaccess? I have read lots of tutorials on how to redirect all traffic to one single page but it didn't helped me.

My problem is, I have a wordpress site before and I decided to remove all my files and uninstall everything under wordpress. In short, I put up a fresh public_html on my server.

I have permanent links given to my clients before like http://domain.com/web/pricing/ or http://domain.com/web-login/uploads/image.jpg. Some of the links contains lots of sub folders like ..domain.com/web/me/you/anyone/none.

I am using this .htaccess code

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I only have two pages on my server right now; index.php and notfound.php. The above code works only if Im trying to visit these kind of url **..domain.com/web** and **..domain.com/web.php** and nothing else.

If I put try to visit **..domain.com/web/me/you/anyone/none** or even a short link that has a slash at the end like **..domain.com/web.php/** it gives me the notfound.php but with lots of errors. CSS and javascripts are not loaded. Only the texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the header of your 2 pages:

```
<base href="/">
```

The additional paths that are added to the URI is probably making the relative links use the incorrect URI base. So if you had:

```
<img src="image/foo.jpg">
```

And it works fine when you request **domain.com/web.php** because the URI base is `/`, but if you request **domain.com/web/me/you/anyone/none**, the URI base is then `/web/me/you/anyone/` and the browser is going to think that the image is at `/web/me/you/anyone/image/foo.jpg`.